# Cannot get the invalidate statement to work

Tags: java, android

```
    package com.game.crazyeights;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import com.game.crazyeights.R;


public class TitleView extends View {

    private Bitmap titleGraphic;
    private Bitmap playButtonUp;
    private Bitmap playButtonDown;
    private boolean playButtonPressed;
    private int screenH;
    private int screenW;

    public TitleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        titleGraphic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.titlegraphic);
        playButtonUp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play_button_up);
        playButtonDown = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play_button_down);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenW = w;
        screenH = h;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(titleGraphic, (screenW-titleGraphic.getWidth())/2 , 0, null);
        if (playButtonPressed) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(playButtonDown, (screenW-playButtonUp.getWidth())/2, (int)(screenH*0.7), null);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(playButtonUp, (screenW-playButtonUp.getWidth())/2, (int)(screenH*0.7), null);
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchedEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        int X = (int)event.getX();
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        switch (eventaction) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (X > (screenW-playButtonUp.getWidth())/2 && X < (screenW-playButtonUp.getWidth())/2 + playButtonUp.getWidth() && Y > (int) (screenH*0.7) && Y < (int) (screenH*0.7) + playButtonUp.getHeight()) {
                playButtonPressed = true;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            playButtonPressed = false;
            break;
    }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically, I tried to put a invalidate at the end to redraw the screen to update the buttons state. What I mean by that is when the button is pressed down on it has a picture of it in a different state I wanna update to but, it doesn't do that when I use the invalidate. And when the user lets go of the button it updates back to the regular button state image..

If you didn't understand what I said above ill try to simplify it. I want the button to update its image when pressed down on, and to go back to its previous image when you stop pressing the button. I tried using invalidate but, it didn't work. Any idea here?

Comment: There is no `ed` in the method `onTouchEvent()` you're trying to override, so it's never getting called. Fix the spelling, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should not place `invalidate()` at the end of the method. `OnTouchedEvent()` is fired every time you touch or move within that `View`.

Make sure that case within `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is called. I mean those boolean expressions are valid. Then call `invalidate()` at the end of that case.

Also I this this method is cumbersome and unnecessary. Instead you can use [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

Good luck!